# Remove only single trailing spaces in vim

Tags: regex, vim

When saving a Markdown file, I’d like to remove single trailing spaces at the end of the line and trim two or more trailing spaces to two.

I’ve tried

```
:%s/\([^\s]\)\s$/\1/gc
```

but that still matches two trailing spaces? Trimming two, seems to work though:

```
:%s/\s\{2,}$/  /gc
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Try `:%s/\([^ ]\) $/\1/gc`.  Maybe `\s` doesn't work. Also try `:%s/([^ ]) $/\1/gc`.  Maybe don't need to escape brackets.

Comment: @Bohemian in Vim patterns, `(` and `)` have to be escaped, unfortunately.

Comment: This isn't off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you could post Vim questions on the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com). They have a more specialized knowledge of Vi and Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `[]`, all characters are taken literally. So you’re effectively saying “any character BUT `\` or `s`", which all white space will match. What you want is `\S` (any non-white space character).

Also, you can make this simpler. Vim has special zero-width modifiers `\zs` and `\ze` to set the start or end point of a match, respectively. So, you could do the following:

```
:%s/\S\zs\s$//gc
```

Broken down:

- `%s/{pattern}//gc` - replace every occurrence of `{pattern}` in the entire file with the empty string, with confirmation
- `\S` - any non-whitespace character
- `\zs` - start match here
- `\s` - any whitespace character
- `$` - end of line

See the following `:help` topics:

```
:h :s
    :h :s_flags

:h pattern-atoms
    :h /[]
    :h /\zs
    :h /\ze
    :h /\$
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and I learned something new too! Thanks 

Answer (score 2):

As an example,

```
%s/\s\+$/\=strlen(submatch(0)) >= 2 ? '  ' : ''/e
```

That is, capture all spaces at the end of line, and substitute it with two spaces if length of match is greater than 2. Pretty straightforward, I believe. See also `:h sub-replace-expression`.